# Demonstrations on the Simplicial complex of Graph

Tags: graph-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, simplicial-complex, monomial-ideals

> [image]

where I cannot understand $F\in\Gamma\land G\subseteq F\Rightarrow G\in\Gamma$. I would like to see an example about the simplicial complex of a graph such as a cycle graph $C_3$.

**What are demonstrations such as $\Gamma (C_3)$ about $\Gamma$?**

Comment: It is hard to see what you aren't understanding.  $F\in\Gamma$ just means $F$ is an element of $\Gamma$, and $G\subseteq F$ just means $G$ is a subset of $F$...there's nothing more to it.

Comment: Since $\{12,23,31\}$ is not a subset of $V$, it can't be an element of $\Gamma$ in your example.  But each of $\{1,2\}$, $\{2,3\}$, and $\{3,1\}$ can be elements of $\Gamma$, so $\Gamma$ has an edge between each pair of vertices.

Comment: $\Gamma$ is just some set of subsets of $V$.  By "edge" I just mean a two-element subset of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

The elements called faces, sometimes called facets, of the simplicial complex $\Gamma$ form a subset of the powerset $\mathcal P(V)$. Each element of $\Gamma (1-2-3)$ and $\Gamma (C_3)$ is called a face, for example the element $1$ in $\Gamma (1-2-3)$ is a face.

*Example on a path graph*

> Consider the path graph $1-2-3$ where the $\mathcal P({1,2,3})=\{\emptyset,1,2,3,12,23,13,123\}$. Now $1,2,3,12,23\in\Gamma$ but $13\not\in\Gamma$ so $123\not\in\Gamma$ so
>
> $\Gamma (1-2-3) =\{\emptyset, 1,2,3,12,23\}\subset\mathcal P(1,2,3)$
>
> where six elements and $\text{dim } \Gamma = \text{dim }(12)=1$.

*Example on $C_3$*

> $\Gamma (C_3) =\{\emptyset,1,2,3,12,23,31,123\}=\mathcal P(1,2,3)$
>
> where eight elements (all elements of the powerset) and $\text{dim } \Gamma = 2$.

Comment: In your path graph, if $13 \notin \Gamma$, you cannot have $123 \in \Gamma$.